# Can we refer angular 2 files from CDN instead of installing them from nodejs

Tags: angular

I have an angularjs 2 application. And I dont have nodejs installed (my company has some restrictions about software and it will take them for them to install it).

Can we refer all the angular files from CDN, instead of NPM it from nodejs.

Do we really need nodejs/npm for angularjs 2 to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. This is how plunkr works. See `system.config.js` and `index.html` of this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXOGwX8bW0AYc86OgVdQ?p=preview)

Node and npm are there to ease the development to bring basic dependencies.

You can work without them with angular2 in JS ( for TS you need tsc installation)

Comment: I had a post here yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044718/angularjs-2-in-visual-studio-2013-not-translpiling). I updated my VS 2013 (RC5) - which solved the traspiling issue (it is converting ts files into js now). But I am getting the other error even now (error loading main.ts) - Any idea whats wrong here ?